# dynamic data display chart plotter in MVVM

Tags: dynamic-data-display

I am trying to use d3 chart plotter in MVVM.

I am trying to use the code given by Ravi  ( https://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/discussions/63633 ) in my project, but not quite sure how to use it properly.

It says "the property Linegraphs is not found in type ChartPlotter" when I try to use it in the XAML code.

What I did is add the LinegraphViewModel.cs to my project and make it the same namespace as my new project.

Anyone can advice me on what should I do in order to use the plotter successfully in my MVVM application?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Data Display is a complex library with many different components. It not enough to pull a single class into your project. You need to reference the d3 .dll to your project to be able to use it's functionality, as well as using the dynamic data namespace in your xaml.

After adding a reference to the library to your project, you can set up the Dynamic Data Display namespace like this :

```
xmlns:dynamicDataDisplay="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
```

Comment: hi Jason,Appreciate your reply. I was trying to use the new namespace written by Ravi. I find using the d3 namespace for MVVM binding pupose as extremely challenging and was looking for a workaround. Thank you for your advice though. I will update again if I find any better solution.

Comment: Hi, I am still struggling on a way to use my line graphs in MVVM pattern. Not very sure on how to get that working. I already have a separate program (non-MVVM pattern) using D3 to draw the charts using plotter, but unable to transport it to MVVM pattern. Any help would be much appreciated!!!